# The data sent to Photon RPC is not accurate on Unity

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, server, photon

I downloaded the photo data using C# WWW class's local dictionary path.

Changed the data www.byte using 'Encoding.Unicode.GetString' to string and send on Photon RPC.

Now, This string data length is 3601.

But, using '[PunRPC]' this length changed to 3708.

So I couldn't restore the original photo data using 'Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes'.

Why is this happening? Could I have done something wrong?

I need help.

---

- PC1.

PhotonView.RPC("ReceiveData", targetPlayer, Encoding.Unicode.GetString(www.byte));

Debug.Log(www.byte.Length) << length is 3601

---

- PC2.

[PunRPC] void ReceiveData(string data)
{

Debug.Log(data.Length)  << length is 3708

}

Comment: This is just a hunch, but try Base64 encoding.